# Mongoid Syntax for running range queries with or condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Suppose we need to write a range query in Mongoid. Let the field to be queried be `range_field`, then we do something like this

```
where(:range_field.lte => some-date-time, :range_field.gte => some-date-time)
```

But if i want to run a query to choose any of multiple ranges, i'd have to do

```
.or({:range_field.lte => some-date-time1, :range_field.gte => some-date-time2},{:range_field.lte => some-date-time3, :range_field.gte => some-date-time4})
```

This apparently doesn't work.
How can I run such queries with Mongoid?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "apparently doesn't work"? Are you getting errors? Is it finding things it shouldn't? Not finding things it should?

Comment: it just runs the greater than equal to query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say:

```
:range_field.lte => some_date_time
```

you're calling a method, `lte`, that Mongoid monkey patches in `Symbol`. That method returns an `Origin::Key` instance that is wrapped around the underlying `$lte` operator. Somewhere inside Mongoid that `Origin::Key` will be converted to something that MongoDB will understand:

```
{ range_field: { $lte: some_date_time } }
```

If you look at what

```
where(:range_field.lte => t1, :range_field.gte => t2)
```

becomes by calling `selector` on the result, you'll see something like this:

```
{
  "created_at" => {
    :$gte => t2,
    :$lte => t1
  }
}
```

and everything will work fine.

However, if we use `#or` and call `selector` to see the underlying query, we see that Mongoid is expanding the `Origin::Key`s one by one and merging the results:

```
or({:range_field.lte => t1, :range_field.gte => t2})
# is expanded as though as you said
or({ :range_field => { :$lte => t1 }, :range_field => { :$gte => t2 } })
# which is the same as
or({ :range_field => { :$gte => t2 } })
```

Essentially, Mongoid is being inconsistent as to how it expands the `Origin::Key`s. You'll even get the same confusing result if you use `:$or` instead of `#or`:

```
where(:$or => [ {:range_field.lte => t1, :range_field.gte => t2} ]).selector
```

will say:

```
{ "$or" => [ { "range_field" => { "$gte" => t2 } } ] }
```

The solution is to not use the `Symbol` monkey patched methods and do that part by hand:

```
or(
  { :range_field => { :$lte => t1, :$gte => t2 } },
  { :range_field => { :$lte => t3, :$gte => t4 } }, 
  ...
)
```